# check button active or not on webpage

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I would like check the button is active or before clicking on the button how can I do that?

My code is

```
Set externalIE = objShell.Windows(x)
Set externalIEDoc = externalIE.Document   
externalIEDoc.getelementsbyname("btnDown")(0).Click
```

Before Click option I would like to check whether button is active or not. How can I check that

Comment: What do you mean by active? Having some "active" class, not being hidden or simply existing on the page?

Comment: Is there an URL to share?

Comment: @ QHarr Sorry I can not share URL as it is Password protected. in my case I want to move to next option I need to click on "btnDown" after all pages it will be inactive, as I don't know how many pages it has I would to stop based on button active or not.

Comment: It sounds like you may need a loop. You will need to determine what is a valid end condition for loop termination. Simply pressing the buttton until an error occurs might be an option and handle the error. Some buttons actually generate a loop back round to item 1 though. Is there anything on the first page that tells you how many pages there are? Or is there an item/some such that is called LastPage? Is there HTML you can share?